# Espacios vacios al ingresar datos a la BD MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Estoy ingresando datos a la BD con PHP y me aparecen espacios vacios donde iria el texto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la estructura de la tabla y el script que estoy usando para ingresar los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**insert.php**

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
 
// Escape user inputs for security
$field1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_REQUEST['field1']);
$field2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_REQUEST['field2']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO lista_espera_cursoav (nombre, email) VALUES ('$field1', '$field2')";
if(mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)){
    echo "¡Recibimos tus datos! Te vamos a notificar cuando el curso este disponible.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
 
// Close connection
mysqli_close($mysqli);
    ?>
```

**Codigo del formulario**

```
  <form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control inputs-landing" id="formGroupExampleInput" name="field1" placeholder="Tu nombre completo">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control inputs-landing" id="InputEmail1" name="field2" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn-landing btn btn-success">Enviar</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: probaste verificar si tiene valor  $_REQUEST['field1'] ? Probar con la Variable $_POST  podes ver https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: @PatrickArguello modifique $_REQUEST por $_POST pero sigue sin ingresar los datos.

Comment: Haz un `echo var_dump($_POST) . "<br>";` para ver qué trae la petición. Eso o incluye en tu pregunta el código del formulario que envía los datos (editándola)...

Comment: Los input de tu formulario tienen el atributo name ?  ej  <input type="text" name="field1"  >

Comment: @PatrickArguello Revisado! El formulario tiene el atributo name.

Comment: @Alfabravo acabo de editar la pregunta con el codigo del formulario!

Comment: Hiciste el var_dump? Mi PHP está oxidado pero juraría que esos viajan con el ID, no con el name :P

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo ! Acabo de intentar el var_dump y me imprime array(0) { } .
Estoy probando en otro servidor y el mismo codigo funciona. Puede ser que sea algo de mi version de php/configuracion?